# Crear una matriz de 3x3 del 0 al 8 lllenados por filas

Tags: python, matriz

Necesito crear un matriz de 3x3 que sea llenado del 0 al 8, lo que llevo es esto

```
filas =3
columnas=3
ma = []
for i in range(filas):
    ma.append([])
    for j in range(columnas):
        valor = i+1
        ma[i].append(valor)

print(ma)
```

Lo unico que he podido imprimir es lo siguiente:

```
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo un array de arrays

```
filas = 3
columnas = 3
matriz = []
n = 0
for i in range(filas):
   if n is 9:
      n = 0
   matriz.append([])
   for j in range(columnas):
      matriz[i][j] = n
   n += 1
```

Comment: Considera agregar una explicación a tus respuestas, de modo que el OP no solo reciba el código sino que además lo pueda entender así como eel resto de la comunidad

Answer (score 1):

En python no existen propiamente arrays, ni vectores, ni matrices. Existen estructuras de datos muy potentes que pueden tener un comportamiento similar a un arreglo como los de otros lenguajes. Esas estructuras son: Listas, tuplas, diccionarios y conjuntos. Recomiendo [leerte un poco sobre ellas](http://docs.python.org.ar/tutorial/3/datastructures.html).

Tu error es que dentro del segundo `for`, le sumas 1 a la variable `i`, la cual solo se incrementa 1 vez mientras el segundo ciclo `for` lo hace 3 veces. Por eso tienes el resultado de 1,1,1 luego 2,2,2 y asi sucesivamente.

Propongo que tengas una variable acumuladora en el ciclo interno, `elem`, la cual se va incrementando a medida que el ciclo va transcurriendo. Esa variable es la que se va añadiendo en cada elemento del arreglo.

```
filas = 3
columnas= 3
# #######
ma = []
elem = 0
for i in range(filas):
    fila = []
    for j in range(columnas):
        fila.append(elem)
        elem += 1
    ma.append(fila)

print(ma)
```

Otra forma de reescribir un código, un poco más comprimido, sería reemplazando la parte de los ciclos `for` por algo como:

```
for i in range(filas):
    ma.append(list(range(columnas*i, columnas*(i+1))))
```

Incluso, el código anterior se puede resumir aún más usando [Comprensión de Listas](http://docs.python.org.ar/tutorial/3/datastructures.html#comprension-de-listas)

```
ma = [[j+i*columnas for j in range(columnas)] for i in range(filas)]
```